# How to connect to second, third, fourth, etc. database from a running web application?

Tags: database, spring, c3p0

I don't have code yet, because this is much more a concept-based question than an actual implementation question, so I bid your license.

I'm working on a Spring based web application and it has its own database for accesses, configurations, the works. But this application must connect to other databases and perform SQL select queries. While the application's (let's call it host) own database is MySQL, it should be able to connect to both MySQL and MS_SQL databases (let's call them guests).

The host should be able to instantiate a connection to a guest, retrieve a  SQL result set and close the connection.

The question here is how should this be done? Using `c3p0`? Some connection factory? I have never faced an issue like this before and would like some help.

Comment: Here I've explained by example how to use two (or more) dataSources (with Spring Boot 1.3): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38483565/spring-boot-secondary-datasource-with-primary-auto-configured/38485465#38485465

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no special relationship between an application and "its" database. For as many databases as you want to access, you have the same basic options.

There is the old-fashioned way, using the static methods of [DriverManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html), and there is the newer way, of instantiating a [DataSource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html) from which Connections may be acquired. An advantage of using a `DataSource` is that it may pool `Connections` for you, improving performance for you (at the cost of some extra thread and memory overhead).

It's very likely that your application accesses your "main" database frequently. Unless your DBMS or application server provides its own implementation of a DataSource with transparent Connection pooling, you almost certainly will want to access this database via a library that provides this for you, such as [c3p0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/) or [HikariCP](https://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/).

For the other databases, if you access them infrequently and if your use of them is not particularly performance sensitive, you might consider just using `DriverManager.getConnection(...)` or a simple, non-pooling implementation of a `DataSource` like c3p0's [DriverManagerDataSource](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/DriverManagerDataSource.html). If you are going to use the other database's frequently, than you will want to access them through a pool-backed DataSource.

(You'll probably want to choose one pooling library and stick with it for accessing all your databases. Nothing prevents you from pooling access to one DBMS with `dbcp`, another with `HikariCP`, another with `c3p0` etc, but you'll be adding useless complexity.)

The main thing you'll have to think about is the tradeoff between speed and memory/thread overhead. For rarely accessed databases, it's usually better not to bother with a Connection pool. For frequently accessed databases, if speed matters at all, you'll almost certainly want to use a pooling library.

Regardless, you can always access as many databases as you want from your app, either via `DriverManager` or via a `DataSource`. JDBC is an elegant, uniform interface to DBMSs. What (little) complexity you face is the decision of which implementations of `DataSource` to use.

Comment: thanks for the input! I will try using the `c3p0` approach. I am using Spring 4 with annotations (no XMLs other than `pom.xml`!). Can you provide a link with an example?

Comment: I'm at best an infrequent Spring user. But it should be no problem to set up a `@Configuration` in which you have multiple `@Bean` annotated methods that set-up all of the `DataSource` instances that you need. The difficulty will be in ensuring that, if you `@Autowired`, the correct `DataSource` instance gets injected where you want it. Again, I have little Spring experience. But, browsing around, it looks like a good way to resolve this will be to add `@Qualifier` annotation next to `@Autowired` specifying the name of the `DataSource` you want injected.

Comment: Also, if you are using c3p0's `ComboPooledDataSource`, be sure to use `@Bean(destroyMethodName="close")`. If you decide some `DataSource` instances do not merit pooling and use c3p0's `DriverManagerDataSource`, these require no cleanup, so just use simple `@Bean`.